# Parse Login Unauthorized Error (code 0)

Tags: ios, facebook, twitter, parse-platform

I have an app using Parse, and am implementing Facebook login.  I believe I've put keys in every place they are required—three keys in the info.plist, the key and secret in Parse settings, and the bundle ID on Facebook Developer.  I am still getting an Error in the Xcode log saying "[Error]: unauthorized (Code: 0, Version: 1.6.3)".  Even using Facebook's code to test the connection causes this error.

Any ideas on what I could be overlooking that would cause this?

**UPDATE**
I just realized this is happening for any kind of login—Twitter, Facebook, or even just the app's login.  They were previously working, and I don't believe I changed anything.

**UPDATE**
This problem occurs on both the simulator and an actual device.

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue, this was driving me crazy already. If you find a solution, please let us know! I will return here if I find anything as well.

Comment: Could something be wrong on Parse's end?  Or is there some little slip-up that we both made?

Comment: I just started studying parse, to be fair. So a slip-up is entirely possible for me. I am currently using parse.com to authenticate through javascript with Phonegap. I get the popup asking my permissions, I give the permissions, and nevertheless I get an "unauthorized" error as a result for Parse.FacebookUtils.logIn

This should have authorised my account and populated the parse.com remote database with my user, right? ain't happening for the moment..

Comment: I'll put this question up for bounty in 2 days so as to draw more attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that this was some sort of error on Parse's end, as all the login functions are now working correctly, with no action on my part.  If you still have a problem, make sure every key is correct, including the Parse initialization keys.

Comment: Well, I am going to review my code then, for me it keeps displaying the "unauthorized" error even though I received an access token for the account. Cheers!

Comment: @milesper are u sure this problem got solved by parse'e end automatically, I am also facing the same problem since 2 days?